# Insert Dynamic Variable Into React Native Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native view i want to style dynamically.
The value of `reaction` will be sourced from an API, so i want to pass it into my styleheet

```
const Weather = ({ reaction, temperature }) => {
//const bg = `weatherconditions.${reaction}.color`
return (
    <View
      style={{ backgroundColor: weatherConditions[reaction].color }}>
```

The stylesheet looks like this

```
export const weatherConditions = {
  Rain: {
    color: '#005BEA',
    title: 'Raining',
    subtitle: 'Get a cup of coffee',
    icon: 'weather-rainy'
  },
  Clear: {
    color: '#f7b733',
    title: 'So Sunny',
    subtitle: 'It is hurting my eyes',
    icon: 'weather-sunny'
  },


Thunderstorm: {
    color: '#616161',
    title: 'A Storm is coming',
    subtitle: 'Because Gods are angry',
    icon: 'weather-lightning'
  },
  Clouds: {
    color: '#1F1C2C',
    title: 'Clouds',
    subtitle: 'Everywhere',
    icon: 'weather-cloudy'
  },

  Snow: {
    color: '#00d2ff',
    title: 'Snow',
    subtitle: 'Get out and build a snowman for me',
    icon: 'weather-snowy'
  },
    }
```

where either `Clear`, `Rain`, `ThunderStorm` can be the value of `reaction`
I want to dynamically provide the `reaction` value.

i have tried to do this

```
const Weather = ({ reaction, temperature }) => {
const bg = `weatherconditions.${reaction}.color`;
return (
    <View
      style={{ backgroundColor: bg }}
    >
```

and

```
<View
    style={{ backgroundColor: ${bg }}>
```

But none of them seem to work.
Any help solving this will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is what you mean but hope it helps.

```
const styles = {
  weather = reaction => ({
    backgroundColor: reaction
  })
}
```

And then in your `<View/>` tag provide the reaction

```
...
<View style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.weather(reaction)])}>
 //Your code here
</View>
```

Comment: To get an object entry dynamically you could try `object[String(outerKey)].innerKey` or you could try the `Object` class. such as `Object.entries(object)` and that will return a pair of data, `key:value`, and access the value by the key. `const color = Object.values(weatherConditions[reaction]).color`